# Looking up text with a string in it

Tags: excel-2010

So I've read a lot about reverse vlookup and looking up text strings within texts in excel, but...
I have a teble with:
Brand Name | Model | Gama

and on another sheet a column:
Device

What I need is to look up values from the "Device" column in the "Model" and show the "Gama" of that device next to it.
Problems are:
1- VLOOKUP or MATCH/INDEX won't let me search for a range or show the result outside of the table matrix (?) I'm looking into
2- In the "Device" cells I have brand, model number, color, device capacity etc, all in the same cell and in no particular order, and "separate by delimitation" will be a month to organize; so I need to look if some part of that cell matches any part of the "Model" cell in the other sheet.

My friends tell me this should be a lot simpler in sql but since I've got minnimal experience even in vba...

I don't even know if this can be done, but thanks in advance anyways.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is not a place to outsource code like this.  You should try something, post what you tried and then the specific problem that you are having with the approach.  I helped with this anyways, but in the future, please try to do this.

Comment: Sorry, code? I've been just using formulas, and gotten nowhere near a solution.  
I've tried  
=DESREF(Hoja1!$A$1,COINCIDIR(Hoja1!G9,Hoja1!$C$3:$C$227),3)  
but then I realized that it doesn't matter that I have the model number separated in "Hoja1!G9" (my office is in spanish) because I'll still need all of the model numbers in the formula.  
Before that tried match:  
=COINCIDIR("*"&Hoja1!G205&"*",Hoja1!C3:C227,0)  
which still only gives me an address, and only looking one model number.  

I have literally no idea how to do this!

Comment: Functions that you've tried, then and the problem with the function you tried.  Another thing you could try is to ask your friends how to do it in SQL.  If it's so simple for them, it should take them a very small amount of time to assist you, and in the process, you'd learn some SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new module and put the following User Defined Function (UDF) into the module:

```
Function testFunc(myRange As Range, myVal As String) As String

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In myRange
         If InStr(1, myVal, myCell.Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
             testFunc = myCell.Address
             Exit Function
         End If
    Next myCell

    testFunc = "NOT FOUND"

End Function
```

Then, in a cell next to your data (in my case cell F3), put:

```
 =testFunc($B$3:$B$6,E3)
```

where you need to replace "$B$3:$B$6" with the column that contains the model numbers.  Replace "E3" with the cell that contains your "device" info.

Then, in the cell to the right of this, put

```
=IF(F3="NOT FOUND", F3, OFFSET(INDIRECT(F3),0,1))
```

Obviously replace "F3" with whichever cell that you put the previous function into.

This will give you the result.

This may not be the *BEST* way to accomplish this, but it'll work.

***EDIT***

If they are on different sheets then edit the line:

```
 testFunc = myCell.Address
```

to

```
testFunc = myCell.Worksheet.Name & "!" & myCell.Address
```

OR

change the formula in the cell to:

```
=IF(F3="NOT FOUND", F3, OFFSET(INDIRECT("SheetName!" & F3),0,1))
```

Comment: I get the "NOT FOUND" message in both columns. 
PS: The "Device" column is in a different sheet (dunno if it matters)

Comment: You need to put the range that the model numbers are in, including the sheet name, so it will look something like "Sheet4!$C$5:$C$8" where "Sheet4" is replaced by the sheet name (you still need the exclamation point) and the cells are replaced by the actual cells.

Comment: Also, be sure you are anchoring the range with $, otherwise when you copy it down, it will move the range.

Comment: Another option is to name the range and then just use the function like "=testFunc(myNamedRange, E3)"

Comment: For clarity, I'd rename the function as "testFunc" is not a good name.  I just used it to demonstrate how this would work.

Comment: Did so, looks like this:  
=testFunc(Hoja1!$C$3:$C$227,Mar!F2)  
and
=SI(G2="NOT FOUND", G2, DESREF(INDIRECTO(G2),0,1))
(spanish excel)

Comment: Put something in the first model in your range (so in cell Hoja!C3, put "TEST") then in cell Mar!F2, put "asfdlkj,TEST,as;lfkj"  what happens then?  If that works, then there's another problem.  I have updated the "If statement" in the code for a possibility (the code as written previously is case sensitive).

Comment: Great! It works now with the edited code. But it´s giving me the cell next to "device" in the same sheet that "Device" is on, I need the cell next to the model number on the other sheet.
Tried changing values in the offset, then I realized that that wasn´t the issue.

Comment: Gave 2 possible solutions to this problem in edit.  Please mark as correct if this works.

Comment: Perfect, this works absolutely beautiful. Thank you so very much!!! This has been giving me a headache this whole week.